# NODEJS,SOCKET on port 8070 connecting on rendering but not directly opening

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io, nodejs-server

I have a cpanel where Apache is activated and displaying my website on port 80,443 https://mydomain.io

The below setup works on port 80 but not on other ports like if I want to run this at Port 8070

I want to run nodejs on port 8070 i.e http://IP:8070

**SERVER SIDE**

server.js

```
var compression = require('compression');
var _       = require('lodash');
var express = require('express');
var server  = express();
var app     = require('http').createServer(server);
var io      = module.exports.io = require('socket.io')(app);
server.use(compression());
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/tester.html');
});
app.listen(8070, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:' + 8070);
});
```

Now when I open this **IP:8070** this renders the HTML and it **connects** to sockets

**WORKING**

`console.log(io.connect());`

But I want to access it via **mydomain.io**

so If I try to go to mydomain.io/tester.html or a file locally on my pc

It doesn't connect to sockets

**//NONE OF THESE WORKING!**

**WITH HTTP GETTING ERR:**

```
   console.log(io.connect('http://mydomain.io:8070/', { transports: ["websocket"]}));
   console.log(io.connect('http://localhost:8070/', { transports: ["websocket"]}));
   console.log(io.connect('http://localhost/', { transports: ["websocket"]}));
   console.log(io.connect('http://mydomain.io/', { transports: ["websocket"]}));
   console.log(io.connect());

GETTIG ERR: Mixed Content: The page at '<URL>' was loaded over HTTPS, but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint 'ws:<URL>/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket'. This request has been blocked; this endpoint must be available over WSS.
```

**WITH HTTPS NOT WORKING**

```
   console.log(io.connect('https://mydomain.io:8070/', { transports: ["websocket"]}));
   console.log(io.connect('https://localhost:8070/', { transports: ["websocket"]}));
   console.log(io.connect('https://localhost/', { transports: ["websocket"]}));
   console.log(io.connect('https://mydomain.io/', { transports: ["websocket"]}));
```

**WITH PORT 80 ITS WORKING BUT NOT ON ELSE**

BUT if I run my server.js at port 80 and stopping apache using `service httpd stop`

then it works with mydomain.io/tester.html or a file locally on my pc

```
var socket = io.connect('wss://mydomain.io'); //Socket Address WOKRING
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add your apache config here as well, are you using apache to setup a reverse proxy to your nodejs server?

Comment: No I don't want a reverse proxy I want node to run seperate and fetch using sockets

Comment: I think this can be fixed if you setup a secure websocket, ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31338927/how-to-create-securetls-ssl-websocket-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Thank you @v1shva, trying https.createserver instead of http createserver with my cpanel keys and cert file I am able to connect with this from anywhere.

Thank You